# Single application kiosk mode Linux mirroring via xrdp

Tags: server, xrdp, kiosk

i need help in understanding how to set up screen mirroring under Ubuntu Server.

I have a simple light Kiosk System built on Ubuntu Server. `nodm` and `matchbox-window-manager` starting my only App on this system. I want to be able to mirror the screen from this Kiosk to a Windows System.

I tried `xrdp` and remote desktop combination, but this doesn't seem to work out of the box. My xinitrc ist pretty basic starting matchbox and starting the app. Also i couldn't find any similar questions.

I can provide any additional information in order to clarify my issue.

Thnx

Comment: If i have to clarify my question  - please point it out to me.